# Proving $(V \oplus V )/ \Gamma \cong V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**Exercise** Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and $T:V \to V$ an isomorphism. the **graph** of $T$ is the subset

$$\Gamma := \{(v, T(v)) \big| v \in V \}$$

Prove $(V \oplus V)/ \Gamma \cong V$.

---

To approach this problem, I rely on a few lemmas/theorems

> $U \cong W \iff \dim(U) = \dim(W)$

> $\dim(U / W) = \dim(U) - \dim(W)$

> $\dim(V + W) = \dim(V) + \dim(W) - \dim(U \cap W)$

---

*Proof*

To prove that $(V \oplus V) / \Gamma \cong V$, we show $\dim((V \oplus V)/ \Gamma) = \dim(V)$.

$\dim(V \oplus V) = \dim(V) + \dim(V) + \dim(V) - \dim(V \cap V) = n +n - 0 = 2n$

$\dim(\Gamma) = 2$ (Since $\{(v,0),(0,T(v))\}$ is a basis for $\Gamma$)

$\dim((V\oplus V)/ \Gamma) = \dim(V \oplus V) - \dim(\Gamma ) = 2n - 2$

But this is not equal to $\dim(V) = n$

---

I suspect that either $\dim(\Gamma) \neq 2$ or I have entirely misunderstood $\dim(V \oplus V)$. Also, it seems suspicious that $\dim(V \oplus V)$ is obtained by adding $n+n - 0$ since all of the basis vectors are the same (and are repeated, in a certain sense).

Can somebody tell me which part of this proof is wrong and how to move forward?

Comment: If $v$ was just one fixed vector then $dim (\Gamma)$ would be $2$, But it is not. $v$ varies over $V$, so dimension of $V$ has to come into the picture, right?

Comment: This can be done without the finite-dimensionality assumption. Define $S : V \oplus V \to V$ by $S(v,w) = Tv - w$. Then $S$ is linear, surjective, and its kernel is $\Gamma$. Thus, the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_A_(modules)) says that $(V \oplus V)/\Gamma \cong V$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  So $\dim(\Gamma) \geq n$?

Comment: @azif00 what is meant by your notation $T_v - w$? Do you mean $T(v-w)$? Or $T(v)-w?$ and what is $w?$

Comment: @EmilyBurkenhamen I mean the second one: $S$ is the function that sends a pair $(v,w) \in V \oplus V$ to $T(v)-w \in V$.